# ERROR deploying ApexPage Syntax error. Found 'IF'

Tags: apex, visualforce, formula, if

I am trying to use IF on my VF page. But I am getting this error. What's wrong?

```
<apex:inputText value="{!IF(CONTAINS(stringOfKeys, item.Id), orders[item.itemId], '')}" id="bVAL"/>
```

Comment: Whats the error?

Answer (score -1):

Please provide the error. But I think you need to replace orders[item.itemId] to orders[item.Id] as below -

```
<apex:inputText value="{!IF(CONTAINS(stringOfKeys, item.Id), orders[item.Id], '')}" id="bVAL"/>
```